# Distinguish between different kinds of configuration changes

Tags: android

I would like to differentiate between configuration changes, e.g. when the screen rotates vs when the user changes the system locale.

In my case, I get some locale-dependent data through an API; when the screen rotates, I don't want to do the call again, however I do want to do it on locale change.

I guess there are "hacky" ways to do such a thing, as in listening for locale change, saving the previous locale etc, but I am looking for something cleaner.

How do people handle caching situations like this in general on configuration change?

Comment: I don't see what locale changing has to do with screen layout

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand what you mean. A configuration change might happen in many cases, 2 of them being locale change or screen rotation. I am using those as examples. After a configuration change, the activity gets restarted. I am wondering if there is any way to define which one actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that this happens to be "locale-dependent data" has little to do with the issue. If it were locale-independent data, you would not necessarily want to do the call again after a configuration change.

So, you should handle your case the same way that everyone else handles the general case. The two main criteria are:

1. Does the data need to survive process termination? If yes, you will need to persist the data (database, `SharedPreferences`, or some other type of file), with perhaps a memory cache for optimization. If no, the memory cache will suffice.
2. How big is the data? If it is on the order of bytes (versus KB/MB), you might put it in the saved instance state `Bundle` as the memory cache. If not, use some process-level cache (e.g., `static` singleton data manager) with appropriate LRU-style caps as the memory cache. Even in that case, you might put some identifying data in the saved instance state `Bundle` to help you know what to reload from the memory cache or from disk if the process gets terminated.

Then, on a configuration change, in the appropriate lifecycle method, see if you have data cached for whatever the current locale is (whether is a different locale or the same one no longer matters). If you do not have cached data for the current locale, go load it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to block certain configuration changes, you can modify the [configChanges](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges) attribute.  Once you have it set to only reload on the types of configurations you want, I suggest to store a static reference to the attributes of the [configuration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html).

For example:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    currentOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

}

public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

    if (currentOrientation != newConfig.orientation) {
        // orientation change
    }

    currentOrientation = newConfig.orientation;

}
```